# Ruby / Capybara - Trying to convert a DOM to JQUERY and add a new HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, dom, capybara

I'm trying to add an "id" for the selector below, However it is not working because the element seems to be a DOM. How can I convert a DOM element for JQuery and then add an "id" attribute?

```
script = '$(".block-header__helper-menu .ml1").attr("id", "tempid")';
page.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the HTML you're dealing with. Have you already found the element via Capybara to make sure it exists before running the script? Also, what is the reason you need to add a temp id, there may be a better solution in Capybara.

Comment: Hi, yes I found the element and it exists, the idea to add an id is because I have a couple elements very similar in every single html attribute, then I would like to add the id the make easier to find each element.. Follow the html below

Comment: FIRST ELEMENT
->
<div class="float-right">
  <nav class="block-header__helper-menu">
     <span class="inline ml1 mr1">
       <button type="button"   class="no-outline"   data-ga-action="zoom-out"
          <span class="text text-small text--300"> A- </span>

Comment: SECOND ELEMENT -> <span class="inline mr1">
       <button type="button"   class="no-outline"   data-ga-action="zoom-in"
          <span class="text text-small text--300"> A+ </span>

Comment: Edit the question with additional information; code/etc in comments is almost always illegible and useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the page you're dealing with has JQuery loaded and you've checked the element exists before running the script then the script you showed should work fine.  However, both of the elements you added in the comments (in the future it would be better if you edited your question so the elements can be formatted better) are invalid since you need to complete (>) the `button` element before opening the child span element.  Not sure if that is due to comment formatting or you have a bug in your html. Assuming the HTML is valid (or you fix it) there really isn't a need to use JQuery to do what you're doing, so if the page doesn't have JQuery loaded then you could do something like

```
page.execute_script('document.querySelector(".block-header__helper-menu .ml1").id = "tempid")
```

If you had already found the element via Capybara (to ensure it exists) then you can do

```
element = page.find('.block-header__helper-menu .ml1')
...
element.execute_script('this.id = "tempid"')
```

That being said, there really is no need to assign ids to these elements.  You just need to use the options available on the Capybara methods to target the individual buttons. To click them you could use the text of the buttons

```
click_button 'A-'
click_button 'A+'
```

or if you just want to find the button elements it would be `find(:button, 'A-')`, etc.

Alternatively you could find the elements by their attribute differences and then click them

```
find('button[data-ga-action="zoom-out"]').click
find('button[data-ga-action="zoom-in"]').click
```

If you really need to find the inline span (not normally the element to be interacted with but the one your initial jQuery targets for adding an id) then you can use the text content to find that too

```
find('span.inline', text: 'A-')
```

etc.